# How to download Dash video files as they appear on the server?

Tags: shell, video, video-streaming, streaming, mpeg-dash

Is it possible, given an mpd file like https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd, to easily download all the Dash files stored on the server (assuming we know that it's static content on the server). That is, I should be able to run an HTTP server serving the content I downloaded, and point a Dash player at it to play the same video.

youtube-dl does not seem to give me the Dash package. I could use curl to perform XHR requests like the browser, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a project that downloads the segments as they are stored on the server: https://github.com/Viblast/dash-proxy

I had to fork it to fix a few things for myself though: https://github.com/elv-peter/dash-proxy

Answer (score 29):

No need to develop a wheel!

The grand tool **youtube-dl** knows hundreds of platforms/protocols/etc as well as MPEG DASH as well as Apple HLS and so on and so forth!
Very often updates/bugfixes

Have fun!

http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/

PS.:
If you want to keep fragments - use the option

```
--keep-fragments
```

Keep downloaded fragments on disk after downloading is finished; fragments are erased by default

Upd:

Your playlist has plenty of options (based on video bandwidth), eg:

```
youtube-dl.exe -F https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_30fps.mpd
[generic] bbb_30fps: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] bbb_30fps: Downloading webpage
[generic] bbb_30fps: Extracting information
[info] Available formats for bbb_30fps:
format code                 extension  resolution note
bbb_a64k                    m4a        audio only DASH audio   67k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.5 (48000Hz)
bbb_30fps_320x180_200k      mp4        320x180    DASH video  254k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64000d, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_320x180_400k      mp4        320x180    DASH video  507k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64000d, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_480x270_600k      mp4        480x270    DASH video  759k , mp4_dash container, avc1.640015, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_640x360_800k      mp4        640x360    DASH video 1013k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64001e, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_640x360_1000k     mp4        640x360    DASH video 1254k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64001e, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_768x432_1500k     mp4        768x432    DASH video 1883k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64001e, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_1024x576_2500k    mp4        1024x576   DASH video 3134k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64001f, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_1280x720_4000k    mp4        1280x720   DASH video 4952k , mp4_dash container, avc1.64001f, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_1920x1080_8000k   mp4        1920x1080  DASH video 9914k , mp4_dash container, avc1.640028, 30fps, video only
bbb_30fps_3840x2160_12000k  mp4        3840x2160  DASH video 14931k , mp4_dash container, avc1.640033, 30fps, video only (best)
```

now, if you wish you download ALL the segments for all the bitrates, you could try to use the magic option

```
--all-formats
```

or you could do it one by one using the 
    --format
option, e.g.:

```
youtube-dl.exe --format bbb_30fps_320x180_200k --keep-fragments
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe in more detail if the Dash package could be found on **youtube-dl**? The OP mentioned that he couldn't found it.

Comment: IIRC, when I tried youtube-dl with --keep-fragments, it did not download files that could be served as Dash. There is also the problem of downloading all the representations and bitrates the Dash MPD offers, i.e. getting the *full* Dash package.

Comment: Yes, some hand improvements either to manifest .mpd file or renaming downloaded fragments would be in need.

Comment: It still works. I found the .mpd video on the site via Chrome Inspector --> Network --> right click on the .mpd row --> Copy --> Copy link address --> open command line --> type youtube-dl your.site.url.address

Comment: What about netflix that is password protected?

Answer (score 1):

You may find that there is actually not an easier way readily available to you, unless someone happens to have built a tool to do this, which I am not aware of.

It worth remembering that a DASH stream will usually have multiple ABR (Adaptive Bit Rate) renditions and the original video on the server will actually be stored in multiple different bit rate versions on the server or CDN.

A normal player will select each chunk or segment of the video from whichever bit rate version is most appropriate for the device type and current network conditions.

So, if you wanted to replicate what was on the original server you would have to create a client which downloaded all the segments from all the available bit rate versions of the video. Or alternatively just download the highest quality version and transcode to the other bitrates yourself.

To actually then serve the DASH streams to somewhere else you would also need to make sure you update the manifest to point to the right URL's on your server.

And finally, you would need to check that you have the rights to share it and that the file is not encrypted, in which case you may not be able to share it with clients.

Comment: I guess the short answer is "no" then. I ended up writing a bash script that downloaded everything for a particular manifest (generalizing the script would be much harder). I'm just surprised no one has made such a tool.

Comment: @PeterTseng Could you share the script? I could maybe generalize it.